# Show errors in Angular2 forms if form items empty, but user submit form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

I have a `userForm` group which has keys `name`, `email` and `phone`. Also I have a `onValueChanged` function which one subscribes to form changes and validate data.

```
 buildForm(): void {
    this.userForm = this.fb.group({
      'name': ['', [
          Validators.required,
        ]
      ],
      'email': [''],
      'phone':    ['', Validators.required]
    });

this.userForm.valueChanges
  .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));
```

Also I have a submit button, but if user doesn't print any data and submit form my errors doesn't show. How can I fix it?

```
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
}
```

This is my errors:

```
formErrors = {
    'name': '',
    // ...
  };

  validationMessages = {
    'name': {
      'required':      'Name is required.',
      'minlength':     'Name must be at least 4 characters long.',
      // ...
    },
    // ...
  };
}
```

My `onValueChanged` function:

```
 onValueChanged(data?: any): void {
    if (!this.registrationForm) return;
    const form = this.registrationForm;

    for (const field in this.formErrors) {
      this.formErrors[field] = '';
      const control: any = form.controls[field];

      if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
        const messages: string = this.validationMessages[field];
        for (const key in control.errors) {
          this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I use my validation in template like this:

```
<div [ngClass]="formErrors.email ? 'has-danger' : '' ">
    <label for="email">Email <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type="email" formControlName="email"  id="email">
    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{formErrors.email}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write `ngif` statements in your component.html(html or your html file). Such as below for `phone` formControl:

```
  <div *ngIf="!phone.valid && (phone.touched || submitted)">Required</div>
```

Added `phone.touched`, so that error displays only after formControl has been touched by user.

Added `submitted`, so that error displays only after user has attempted to submit form.